# Nested <kbd>s look weird

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

<kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd></kbd>

^ Just why?

Can `kbd kbd` get different formatting? How about a nested samp?

```
<kbd><kbd><samp>File</samp></kbd> <kbd><samp>Save</samp></kbd></kbd>
```

<kbd><kbd>File</kbd> <kbd>Save</kbd></kbd>

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @SantaClaus That's how the spec says you're supposed to use it.

Comment: @bjb568 what spec? link?

Comment: @JanDvorak http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-kbd-element.html

Comment: Not that it matters, but bootstrap added special styling for this. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/14168

Comment: Related from MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215133/can-we-use-kbd-according-to-its-definition-in-html5

Comment: I read @Santa's _"Why would you want to do this?"_ not as why would you want to add `<samp>` tags but why on earth would you want to use nested `<kbd>`s anywhere?

Comment: @Ben Semantic HTML? …

Comment: @Ben When I commented, the question didn't actually say anything about `<samp>`, so you are correct.

Comment: Sorry @bjb, I'm not a front-end web-dev so while I understand the concept I still see no need for nested kbd's... I understand from your link that w3 have stated that that is the standard for key-presses but I have no idea why and unless they can convince the ordinary masses it won't be.

Comment: @Ben One usage is, for example, to identify the sequence `(Ctrl+C), (Shift+D)` as distinguished from `(Ctrl), (C), (Shift), (D)` or `(Ctrl+C+Shift+D)` -- presuming that `(Ctrl+C)` and `(Ctrl+D)` are a single "unit" of input each, as it were.

Comment: You managed to explain that very well without needing them @Jason!

Comment: @Ben That's not a valid argument against (although I'm not sure why anybody would care to argue either way) as it can be said about virtually all markup. Text has always been effective for communication. Formatting is a bonus.

Comment: @JasonC That's part of the feature request - there should be.

Answer (score 4):

As to why you would want to nest them, here it is from the [horse's mouth](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-kbd-element.html):

> When the kbd element is nested inside another kbd element, it
>   represents an actual key or other single unit of input as appropriate
>   for the input mechanism.

[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd) give two examples of `kbd` usage, one of which uses nesting:

```
<p>Save the document by pressing <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd></kbd></p>
```

They show the results below on the same page.

Comment: The horse is an HTML5 draft, work in progress, containing a rather contrived idea here. The idea might be partly based on usage shown at the start of the question, the Ctrl + C case. Approved HTML specifications do not say anything about nesting `kbd` (except that syntactically they can be nested).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela indeed. And indeed I have no particular allegiance--not flogging an unborn horse--just giving the full quote for clarity, as a few were wondering about it since bjb568 first provided the link

Answer (score 1):

Nested `kbd` elements look what they look at SO just because SO defines their style so that they look like buttons of a kind. If you nest them, the result thus looks like a button inside a button. The button-like appearance is meant to make things look like keyboard keys, more or less. The practical implication is that at SO, you should use `kbd` only for describing keypresses.

Since `kbd` means user input (or specifically keyboard input), there is no logical reason to nest `kbd` elements. There is often need to indicate that some keypresses belong together (e.g., you are expected to press the “C” key while keeping the “Ctrl” key pressed down, instead of pressing first “Ctrl”, then “C”). There is no really satisfactory way to do that. You normally need to rely on general understanding or on verbal explanations.

Comment: I know how it works. But how it works can be changed. If how it works doesn't comply with the spec, how it works should change.

Comment: @bjb568: Jukka's point is there is no reason to change it. One can think of oodles of unlikely combo's, say, "should `<i>..</i>` nested in itself be regular again?"

Comment: @bjb568: SO's markup doesn't have to comply with the spec for HTML. It's markup used at SO. Feel free to write HTML anywhere else you like and ask them to support the standard if their site says that they do so.

Comment: @KenWhite Nobody has to do anything, that doesn't mean that they shouldn't.

Comment: @bjb568: It works as designed here for the purpose it's designed to be used here. Why should it change? Because you say so?

Comment: @KenWhite Because the spec says so.

Comment: @bjb568: Terrific. We've circled right back to my first comment to you. Can you read it again and save me typing it over?

Comment: @KenWhite My point is that SO should comply with the spec.

Comment: @bjb568: Yes, I know. We've been over that already. Are you even reading what you and I have been typing? Start again at the top of these comments and re-read them all again.

Comment: @KenWhite … and your point is that compliance is worthless?

Comment: @bjb568: No. Read **my first comment again**, which clearly states the point I'm making. (Gosh, I really feel like we're going around and around in circles here. You don't read, say something that's been said before, I remind you it's  been said before, you don't read, say something else that's been said before, I remind you...)

Comment: @KenWhite "SO's markup doesn't have to comply with the spec for HTML." So? It should. "It's markup used at SO." On the web. In HTML. "Feel free to write HTML anywhere else you like and ask them to support the standard if their site says that they do so." So I should ask sites that already support it to support it and not sites that don't?

Comment: @Jongware That's... not even relevant. Italicized text nested within italicized text should be, well, italicized. If some website randomly put 5px of padding on all their italicized text, then nesting them inside each other suddenly becomes extremely irritating. Sure, there might have been a good reason to do that for a *single* one, but they definitely should have thought about what happens with multiple nested elements. -- Aside: I don't particularly care if Stack Exchange changes their CSS to compensate, I have my custom CSS that makes my page look pretty. If others don't care, oh well.

Comment: @bjb568: You're not writing HTML, though. You're writing SO markup. If you were writing plain HTML, you could include tables and other things that are not permitted at SO. The fact they're *displayed* as HTML doesn't mean that's what you're permitted to write. And I said you should discuss problems with missing standards support with sites that tell you they support them but don't; SO doesn't make that claim. They claim to support the markup that is allowed at SO.

Comment: @KenWhite Are you denying the fact that SO uses HTML? Sure they sanitize it but how is that relevant?

Comment: @bjb568: No, of course not. Don't be ridiculous. I'm saying that when **you** post to SO and use certain markdown, you're **using markdown** that may include sanitized HTML (but it may include something else totally as well). I give up; you're clearly trying to argue by injecting meaning into my words that isn't even close to what I actually wrote.

Comment: @KenWhite Even if this thing that looks *suspiciously like HTML* is not meant to be like HTML (it is), people expect it to behave like HTML (because it is). It's beneficial to comply with the spec because that's what people expect.

Comment: @KenWhite *"Why should it change? Because you say so?"* Granted this post has received negative feedback and thus nothing here will likely be changed, but note that the negative feedback is negative *community* feedback. Just like positive feedback would have been positive *community* feedback. To ask something like "Why? Because *you* said so?" on *any* SE request/suggestion is complete and utter  nonsense. You know exactly how our system works, don't pretend you don't just because you want to come across as sharp. "Why?" Because he was hoping *many* would say so (which they did not).

Comment: @Jason: I asked for an explanation of why a feature change was being requested, as there's no clear description of a problem in the post. I'm not sure why you feel the need for a personal attack here. As you say, I know **exactly** how our system works here, and requests for functional changes or feature additions should contain some actual justification for the request, and there was none provided. "It works perfectly fine for this site's designed use, but I want it changed because it doesn't meet a standard that doesn't necessarily apply here" is not justification, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure out what you were talking about, then I realized I have custom CSS to fix this annoying issue:

```
kbd kbd, blockquote blockquote {
    background: none;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Note I also use these same styles to prevent the annoying nested blockquotes.

Comment: I don’t see how this answers any of the questions asked. It may well be a good answer, but to different question.